# InfoWindow "View on Google Maps" link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In previous google maps versions (3.32-3.33), one could specify a property named `place` in `MarkerOptions` when creating a `Marker`.  Then, when opening an `InfoWindow` and using that `Marker` as anchor to position it, a link "View on Google Maps" was automatically added to the `InfoWindow` content.

This [sample using 3.33 demonstrates this](https://jsfiddle.net/fastfasterfastest/gh27bwo6/2/) - click on the marker and note the "View on Google Maps" link appearing in the `InfoWindow`.

This behavior used to be [documented at 3.exp which is no longer available](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerPlace) (but see https://web.archive.org/web/20171014093717/developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference), and although it doesn't appear it is/was documented in the [official docs for e.g. 3.33](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.33/marker#MarkerOptions), the sample referenced above shows it in action.

Starting with 3.34, however, there is no "View on Google Maps" link automatically added to the `InfoWindow`, see [this sample using the latest version](https://jsfiddle.net/fastfasterfastest/gh27bwo6/1/) - it is the same sample just referencing the latest version of google maps.

Was this functionality deliberately dropped in 3.34?
Or, is it a bug?
Or, is one supposed to use another way to get a "View on Google Maps" automatically added to the `InfoWindow` in 3.34 by specifying some other option?
Or, does one now have to add such a link manually?

Comment: I had actually never seen that before. But as the name says, "experimental" version of the API is, well... experimental. So you might see stuff in there that will never make it to the release version, or which might make it at a later point. Until it is implemented in the release version, the answer provided below by @geocodezip will work just fine! Check the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) for future version updates.

Comment: The `place` property of `MarkerOptions` was in the non-experimental documentation as well, e.g. see [API Reference - Release 3.31](https://web.archive.org/web/20180503052259/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#MarkerOptions) and I don't see any mentioning of it being dropped in the release notes for any of the versions.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't get that. Then maybe it made it to the release by mistake. If you want to know more, you can always open a new bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853%20status:open).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the answer to your questions about whether this is a bug or if it was deliberately dropped, but that link just points to the URL in the place object returned by the places `getDetails` request.

You can add it yourself to the infowindow like this:

```
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' + 
      place.formatted_address + '</div>'+
      // add "view on google maps
      '<div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 9px; padding: 6px; font-size: 13px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Roboto, Arial;">'+
      '<a href="'+place.url+'" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(66, 127, 237); text-decoration: none;">View on Google Maps</a></div>'
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gh27bwo6/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.866,
      lng: 151.196
    },
    zoom: 15
  });

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
  }, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location,
          place: {
            location: place.geometry.location,
            placeId: place.place_id
          }
        }),
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' + place.formatted_address + '</div>' + '<div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 9px; padding: 6px; font-size: 13px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Roboto, Arial;"><a href="' + place.url + '" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(66, 127, 237); text-decoration: none;">View on Google Maps</a></div>' +
            '<div>API version ' + google.maps.version + '</div>'
        });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```